# Chat app sending method

Tags: database, chat, real-time, message

I'd like to make a chat app, but I don't know how to send the messages in real time. Should I write them into a database, and retrive them on the other side, or should I use sockets for real time messaging? (I would use a database in both  cases for reading old messages)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using sockets for real time communication and execute job in background that would store these messages into database. Whenewer the user opens the conversation you can load recent messages from database. Otherwise I think there could be a problem with real time sync with the database. Hope this helps.